# Extracting a 2.7GB 7z file

Tags: debian, kali-linux, 7z

I currently have a 2.7GB 7z file that backed up my computer (it extracts to about 6.2GB of data) I am running on a Chromebook with [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/). The Chroot is running Kali with a Unity front end. I am trying to extract the 7z file using the p7zip package. I keep getting the following error.

```
(kali)austin@localhost:~/zip$ 7z x backup.7z

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=C,Utf16=off,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Processing archive: backup.7z

Error: Can not open file as archive

(kali)austin@localhost:~/zip$
```

I figure I am either missing an argument or something and I realize this might be a localized problem, however I don't know where else to turn for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you got almost certainly means that `backup.7z` is not a 7zip archive, or has been corrupted.  You can check the "not a 7zip archive" option by running `file backup.7z` and seeing what it says.

(Incidentally, while verifying this, I discovered that `7z` can disassemble a .dll file into its component sections -- which made reproducing the error message a bit difficult)

Comment: This is definitely not a result of the file size. As @Mark said, this could be corrupt. Or some idiot just renamed something to the .7z extension when it could really be anything else.

As he said, `file backup.7z` will tell us more. Please post the results.

If it was just a big file, it would start extracting and hog resources for a while.

Comment: My problem was that the file that I had was 2.7GB when the other copy of the file (I just found today) is only 2.45GB. I don't know where the other .2GB game from but that is my issue. It was actually corrupt.